# gradle war doesn't include classes

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, gradle, war

The Gradle 'war' plugin doesn't include my class files. It did before, with this exact project structure, but for some reason it doesn't anymore and I can't figure out what it is.

This is my project structure:

```
|PROJECT-ROOT
|---|src
|   |---|main
|       |---|java
|           |---|JAVA PACKAGES HERE
|build.gradle
|---|statics
|   |---|STATIC FILES HERE (yup I know, you can put them in src/main/webapp but this is better for my purposes)
|---|WEB-INF
|   |---|web.xml
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'catalina', version: '6.0.20'
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'
}

war {
    from('lib') {
        into 'WEB-INF/lib'
    }
    from('statics') {
        into ''
    }
    webInf {
        from 'WEB-INF'
    }
}
```

Comment: It adds classes pretty well. Version 1.12 used. Here You have an example: https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow

Comment: @Opal what task do you use? Just 'war'?

Comment: Yes, `gradle clean war`

Comment: The clean task seems to make the difference :)